# JS/TS: How can I turn a factory function into a more functional pattern?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, refactoring

I've refactored a class into a module where every function needs a helper function to work.

#### OO Class

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(config) {
    this.helper = new Helper(config);
  }

  fooMethod (arg) {
    return this.helper(arg);
  }
}
```

#### Factory Method

```js
const fooFN = (helper) => (arg) => helper(arg);

export default Foo (config) => {
  const helper = new Helper(config);

  return {
     fooMethod: fooFN(helper)
  }
}
```

This helper function is initialised in a factory function, which returns the partial of all functions which are needing the helper method.

IMO this is not the end of the road. The differences to a class are minimal and there could be another more functional way to write this, but I cannot get my head around it.

**How can I pass a helper function to each exported member of a module without initialising the helper each time I call the member?**

Comment: You sure you need it functional? Since it seems you just need dependency injection for `Helper`. Or maybe as simple as doing `import helper from './helper'` which will give you a singleton instance of `Helper`.

Comment: Is `this.helper` an object or a function? It's initialized as `new Helper(config)`. However, it's being used as a function, i.e. `this.helper(arg)`.

Comment: @AaditMShah it's an arbitrary function or class, which has to be created with a config and can then be used.

Comment: @VLAZ It's more like an experiment of thoughts, how I modularize it as much as possible. The suggestion to import a singleton is interesting, but then I cannot configure it, could I?

Comment: @DanielderGrosse OK, I missed the configuration aspect. You can always just take the next step after singletons and just make a pool of `Helper` instances. You would have some factory and call something like `getHelper(config)` and either get a new object or, if you've already received this configuration, return an existing instance. This is, of course, a step or two behind dependency injection just doing this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your object-oriented code.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(config) {
    this.helper = new Helper(config);
  }

  fooMethod (arg) {
    return this.helper(arg);
  }
}
```

Here is how I would refactor it into a functional style.

```js
const Foo = helper => ({ helper }); // constructor

const fooFunction = (foo, arg) => foo.helper(arg); // fooMethod
```

You'd use it as follows.

```js
const foo = Foo(Helper(config)); // new Foo(config)

fooFunction(foo, arg); // foo.fooMethod(arg);
```

As you can see the code is more terse. In addition, it's simpler because you don't use `this` or `new`.

---

**Edit:** If you're worried about importing too many things then you could use a namespace import.

```js
import { Helper } from "./helper";

export const Foo = helper => ({ helper }); // data constructor

export const Foo2 = config => Foo(Helper(config)); // constructor

export const fooFunction = (foo, arg) => foo.helper(arg); // fooMethod
```

You'd use it as follows.

```js
import * as F from "./foo";

const foo = F.Foo2(config); // new Foo(config)

F.fooFunction(foo, arg); // foo.fooMethod(arg);
```

To quote the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), “Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!”

Comment: I already had this solution too, but it would mean, that I have to import the single functions and the helper functions as well and only to use it together. Somehow I thought I could go with the dot style.

Comment: You could always compose them, i.e. `const Foo2 = config => Foo(Helper(config));`. Then you simply export `Foo2` instead of `Foo`. Hence, the example would become `const foo = Foo2(config);`.

Comment: Also, if your concern is importing individual functions then you can always use a namespace instead. For example, `import * as F from "./foo";`. Then you can use the functions `F.Foo` and `F.fooFunction`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good so far. I'm still looking for another way to do this, but currently it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason to remove the `.helper` property from your objects. You could just write

```
function fooMethod(arg) {
  return this.helper(arg);
}

export default function(config) {
  return {
     helper: Helper(config),
     fooMethod,
  }
}
```

That way `fooMethod` is reused, just like with `class` syntax.

Comment: This has the downside, that I have to mock the helper function in my tests. With the above solution I can give it just as argument. 
Either way thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, if that is important, you could use dependency injection here as well, and use `function(helper) { return { helper, fooMethod }; }` as the factory function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather leverage on composition and avoid any class at all.

1. It doesn't have to be a class since it is not really relying on any internal state or context.
2. We know that `fn` is not usable unless it is provided the `helper` dependency.

```js
function Helper(config) {

  return (...args) => console.log({ config, args });
}

const withHelper = (helper) => (...args) => helper(...args);

const foo = withHelper(new Helper({ name: 'foo' }));
const baz = withHelper(new Helper({ name: 'baz' }));

foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
baz('Hello', 'World');
```